# Is there a way to generify lambda?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda that will implement a `@FunctionalInterface` (`BiFunction` in this example) and will return an object generified with `<T>`.

I can do it with the old approach declaring a generified class (see `class Extractor<T>`), but I do not understand how to do it with lambda. The only thing I am able to do is to declare a lambda with "unknown" `<?>` generic type.

Basically, I want to declare a lambda that is possible to pass to `method2`. Is it possible?

```
private BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<?>> extractorLambda = 
    (fieldName, root) -> root.get(fieldName);

class ExtractorClass<T> implements BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<T>> {
    @Override
    public Path<T> apply(final String fieldName, final Root<Employee> root) {
        return root.get(fieldName);
    }
}

private Specification<Employee> method1(String fieldName,
                                        BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<?>> extractor) {
    return null;
}

private <T> Specification<Employee> method2(String fieldName,
                                            BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<T>> extractor) {
    return null;
}


public void main(String[] args) {
    method1("s", extractorLambda); // ok
    method2("s", extractorLambda); // error
    ExtractorClass<String> extractorClass = new Extractor<>();
    method2("s", extractorClass);               // ok
}
```

Comment: `Extractor<ABC> extractor = (fieldName, root) -> root.get(fieldName);`

Comment: Shouldn't the type of `EXTRACTOR` be `Extractor<String>`, instead of `BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<?>>`?

Comment: Then there is no point in having a lambda, because then I need to have `Extractor<T> ` class declared. I decalred it here only to show that it is possible to generify at "class level" with <T>,  but how to get the same with declaring only lambda, that implements BiFunction?

Comment: You can make `Extractor` an interface and extend `BiFunction`, then it could be used as the target of a lambda. However, I'm having a hard time understanding the purpose of `EXTRACTOR`. If you have a method that cares about the generic type of `Path`, why do you want to use a singleton which states the generic type of `Path` is unknown?

Comment: @Slaw, probably my question is not very clear as everyone gets confused by this `Extractor` class, but what I want to achieve is to make lambda be specifically generified with `<T>` instead of `<?>` (nevermind if it is static or final) just like the Extractor class. Basically, I want to declare a lambda that will be passed to `method2`

Comment: The problem is that `T` is not really a type, it's a placeholder. In your context, using `T` does not make much sense—what type is it supposed to represent? Don't forget about _type-erasure_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is difference between `<T>` and `<?>`.

Your method2 expects List of objects of one type. `<?>` is unbounded wildcard that means it can contain whatever as long as it extends Object.

Same applies in other direction. If you try to use your Extractor class with method1, it won't compile because class says it works just for lists of certain type.

As far as I know you can't have generic type definition on field.
Based on your comment this looks like shortest workaround:

```
    private interface E2<T> extends BiFunction<String, Root<Employee>, Path<T>>{}
    private static final E2 EXTRACTOR = (fieldName, root) -> root.get(fieldName);
```

Comment: Ok, I got it, but can I re-work my lambda so that it will comply with `method2`?

Comment: I updated my answer. From what I know you will end up basically with old approach. Well, what we would expect when lambdas are just syntactic sugar above old approach.

Comment: Indeed looks so. I came to the conclusion that it is a limitation of anonymous classes: unlike usual classes they cannot be generified at class level and therefore lambdas (which are sugar above anonymous classes) cannot too. Please correct me if I'm wrong.